# apt programmatically detect upgradable packages after update

Tags: apt

When running `apt-get update`, it downloads the package list and if there are upgradable packages it outputs something like

```
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

I could parse the output grepping for "can be upgraded" or something similar, but there must be a more elegant way to know if there are packages that be upgraded after doing an update.

I noticed that `apt-get update` outputs this information nearly immediately after downloading the data, while if i run `apt list --upgradeable` it takes a long time, presumably because it does not just tell me how many packages there are, but goes on to produce a full list of them, which I don't need. I just need to quickly know if there are any packages to update.

Note: an answer that requires to use a programming interface to apt to do this would be acceptable

Comment: As you already said `apt update` quickly tells you how many packages need upgrading. Later on you say this all you need to know. Could you clarify what exactly you do need?

Comment: I need this information available to other scripts, so that I can take action if there are packages that need upgrading. Grepping the output of ```apt update``` is doable but unsafe, so I am looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time it takes to list the items is short AFTER you have done a `sudo apt update`...

Example:
*(I forgot to add "time" to the first)...*

```
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libpython2.7/xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8]
libpython2.7-dev/xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8]
libpython2.7-minimal/xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8]
libpython2.7-stdlib/xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8]
libpython3.5/xenial-security 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8]
libpython3.5-dev/xenial-security 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8]
libpython3.5-minimal/xenial-security 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8]
libpython3.5-stdlib/xenial-security 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8]
python2.7/xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8]
python2.7-dev/xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8]
python2.7-minimal/xenial-security 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.8]
python3.5/xenial-security 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8]
python3.5-dev/xenial-security 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8]
python3.5-minimal/xenial-security 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.9 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.8]
hannu@wkbx ~ bash (P)PID=(19384)23069, s=0

$ time apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
0.326 seconds elapsed, p=100.03, 0.326 real, 0.318 user, 0.008 sys.
```

So... this will give you `$items` set to the number of available updates:

```
$ items="$(( $(apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | grep upgradable | wc -l) - 1 ))" ; echo $items
0
```

Now, use bash conditionals to    determine which commands to execute based on it.

Comment: www.tldp.org - read the guides on bash-programming to get started.

Comment: I say in the original question that ```apt list --upgradable``` takes a long time to produce that list, which is not good for me. While ```apt update``` nearly instantly tells me that there are packages that can be upgraded, which would be what I need if it did not require me to parse the output.

Comment: And I tell you above that it depends on what you have done just before it. `apt list --upgradeable` is quick after an update - I take it to be solely dependent on the communication speed to the server you happen to connect to. Something you will probably not be able to change much regardless of what you try.

Comment: Ok, I have done some more tests, and it turns out that the difference was because of the fact that when calling apt update I am asking it to just use a specific source list, for a repository where there are very few packages, and ignore the system ones. I did not mention this because I thought it would not make much of a difference, but it does

Comment: Nice one-liner +1

Comment: Additional `grep` in the one-liner, it appears the output isn't always as clean as shown above.